# How to implement a disable when loading directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a variable on my scope named loadingdata. It will have the values true or false to determine if data is loading or not. I would like to put an attribute on an element to disable it if data is loading. Here is the code I already have but it is not working:

```
module.directive('disableWhenLoadingData', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {},
                link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                    $scope.$watch('loadingData', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                        element.attr('disabled', newValue);
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

any ideas

Comment: Looks like you haven't set any binding for it in the `scope` option: `scope: { loadingData: '=' }`? (of course you'd also have to set that attribute in the view)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Angular's own [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

Service:

```
module.factory('GetDataService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getCustomers: function() {
            return $http({ url: '/someurl', method: 'GET'});
        }
    }
});
```

Directive:

```
 module.directive('disableWhenLoadingData', function (GetDataService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.loadingData = true;
                GetDataService.getCustomers().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.loadingData = false;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I set $scope.loading in my controller, and my button or whatever i set ng-disabled.

In my controller:

```
$scope.loadData = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http
        .get('url')
            .success(function (ret) {
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
}
```

In my view:

```
<button ng-disabled="loading" ng-click="loadData()">{{loading? 'loading Data' : 'Submit'}}</button>
```